# Dynamically determine data type of a variable

Tags: rust

I have a struct where I define variables and their data type:

```
pub struct Post {   
    pub ts: i64,    
    pub uid: u32,    
    pub gid: u32, 
    pub st: u8,   
}
```

I would like to change the data type of `uid`, based on the value of that variable. So if it is 10, it should be a `u8`, if it's 300 it should be `u16`, etcetera.

I am trying to minimize space, so would like to dynamically increase or decrease the bytes allocated to a hold a variable.

Does anyone have a pointer on where I should be thinking of to do this?

Comment: This is completely infeasible to do. Ignoring the fact that dynamically sized types are a nightmare to work with and that memory alignment will probably make 1 byte differences irrelevant, how could you possibly tell the difference between a u8 and u16 when reading? You'd need another 1-byte tag, which is just a waste of space and completely goes against your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of the variable is not the right way to go. Instead, you want to have a single type that allows increasing its size (not all types are `Sized`), and probably put it behind an owned pointer. Turns out something like that already exists, and it's just a `Vec`! You could do what you are looking for with a `Vec<u8>` (that is, if your number fits in a single `u8`, then you only have a `Vec` of length one, otherwise you keep adding bytes), but the core logic is the same as of big integers libraries. For instance, you could try [num-bigint](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/latest/num_bigint/), but I'm not sure it will actually save you a lot of memory space, because it is optimized for big numbers (not those that can fit in `u8`).

Comment: OP is trying to save memory. The 3 `usize`s that make up a `Vec` accompanied with a heap allocation (which is usually going to be padded to at least 16 bytes) are much larger (not to mention slower) than just using a `u32` or `u64`.

Comment: @Aplet123 I agree, but I don't think there is any other way...